# java functions equivalent in php

Tags: java, php

I have a web service written in java and I have a java client example to call the web service as below:

```
private static String hash(String value) throws NoSuchAlgorithmException {
        byte[] data = value.getBytes(StandardCharsets.US_ASCII);
        MessageDigest md = MessageDigest.getInstance("MD5");
        byte[] result = md.digest(data);
        return Hex.encodeHexString(result).replace("-", "").toLowerCase();
}
```

I want to develop client file in php but I do not know how to write these functions in php. What is this code snippet in php?

Answer (score 1):

PHP has a built in MD5 hashing function that will return the result in hex by default as detailed [here](http://php.net/manual/en/function.md5.php)  So something like:

```
<?php
function hash($value) {
    return strtolower(str_replace("-", "", md5($value)));
}
?>
```

should do you.